# Strange behavior in a code to test a thread-safe singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, enums, singleton

I'm rather new to multi-threading in Java. As I need a thread-safe singleton (which I implemented as an enum), I wrote a small test-code which produces a strange output.

The Code:

```
public enum EnumSingleton {
    INSTANCE;


    /** state variables */
    private String message;

    /** Constructor */
    private EnumSingleton() {
    }

    /** add well-known accessor for the instance  (is NOT necessary) */
    public static EnumSingleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    /** Accessors */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String name) {
        this.message = name;
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int b = i;
            Thread thread = new Thread("Thread #" + b) {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EnumSingleton singleton = EnumSingleton.getInstance();
                    singleton.setMessage("Message written by "+this.getName());
                    System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage());
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So every thread writes its name in the property "message" of the enum which is then printed to STDOUT. I get the following output which I find strange:

```
Current thread Thread #6: Message written by Thread #3
Current thread Thread #1: Message written by Thread #1
Current thread Thread #8: Message written by Thread #8
Current thread Thread #5: Message written by Thread #1
Current thread Thread #4: Message written by Thread #4
Current thread Thread #9: Message written by Thread #9
Current thread Thread #7: Message written by Thread #3
Current thread Thread #2: Message written by Thread #3
Current thread Thread #0: Message written by Thread #3
Current thread Thread #3: Message written by Thread #3
```

What I expected is that i get for every loop counter (0-9) a message. But in this example I have multiple messages written by Thread #3, how can that be? Is there a race-condition?

If my code is crap: How do I correctly test my singleton for thread-safety?

Comment: enums already are singletons, what more do you need?

Comment: @Stultuske : thread-safety and testability, but first of all, I want to understand "it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a clear race condition here as you have a variable `message` inside the singleton instance of the enum. Your threads are all writing to and reading from that variable at the same time so you would expect to see results like this.

The enum construct means that the *creation* of your singleton object is thread safe, however calls to methods within it still need to be properly handled.

The way to do what you are looking for would be to have `message` be a [thread local](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable or to place the setting of the message and the reading of it inside a single `synchronized` block, probably locking on the singleton object.

Comment: You're assuming a lot about what they are "looking for."  The fact that a `ThreadLocal` can make his learning test produce an expected result does not mean that a `ThreadLocal` will help to solve the actual problem that motivated him to write the test.  I mention this because `ThreadLocal` is something I rarely see in production code, and when I do see it, the code usually is doing something way too complicated to entrust to somebody who's just learning to use threads.

Answer (score 5):

You singleton is not thread safe - you have not done anything to guarantee the visibility of the `message` variable.

You could make it `volatile` for that. Note however that the output could be many different things - in particular you won't necessarily get one `Message written by Thread #i` for each `i`.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is:

- Thread #7 `singleton.setMessage("Message written by #7");`
- Thread #2 `singleton.setMessage("Message written by #2");`
- Thread #0 `singleton.setMessage("Message written by #0");`
- Thread #3 `singleton.setMessage("Message written by #3");`
- Thread #7 `System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage())`
- Thread #2 `System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage())`
- Thread #0 `System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage())`
- Thread #3 `System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage())`

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed two different things. One is whether and object is a singleton and whether an object is mutable/immutable. In your case you do have a singleton object which however is mutable.

That means that the threads do get the same object instance and mutate the state of the `EnumSingleton` object.

In your case you want to make the object immutable or do something like below:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int b = i;
        Thread thread = new Thread("Thread #" + b) {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                     EnumSingleton singleton = EnumSingleton.getInstance();
                     singleton.setMessage("Message written by "+this.getName());
                     System.out.println("Current thread "+this.getName() + ": "+singleton.getMessage());
                }

            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

The whole point of the lock object above is to make the operation of setting and getting the message an Atomic operation. You cannot get away with just making `setMessage()` and `getMessage()` methods synchronized.